# Snakemake changes wildcard, resulting in InputFunctionException

Tags: snakemake

I keep getting the same errors at the same step in the pipeline. I have 2 rules named `typing` and `apply_qc` which somehow conflict. `typing` uses outputs from another rule, `polish_consensus`, and `apply_qc` uses the outputs of `typing` (so the order: `polish_consensus > typing > apply_qc`). The outputs of `typing` are a fasta and CSV file. `apply_qc` is a quality control step, which will censor the data of these files when of low quality. Now I keep getting the same errors with the rules:

1.
The code:

```py
rule typing:
    input:
        f"{DATA_FOLDER}/vaccines.fasta",
        rules.polish_consensus.output
    output:
        temp(f"{OUTPUT_FOLDER}/typing/{{samplename}}.csv")
    script:
        "../scripts/typing.py"

rule apply_qc:
    input:
        rules.typing.output,
        rules.polish_consensus.output,
        rules.featurecounts.output.summary
    output:
        typing=f"{OUTPUT_FOLDER}/typing/{{samplename}}_qcpass.csv",
        consensus=f"{OUTPUT_FOLDER}/consensus/{{samplename}}_qcpass.fasta"
    script:
        "../scripts/apply_qc.py"
```

The output of the rule `polish_consensus` is `output/consensus/{samplename}.fasta` with `samplename=prrsv12`.

The error:

```
InputFunctionException in rule typing in file /home/lisah/Pycharm/minor-HTHPC/snakemake/workflow/rules/typing.smk, line 1:
Error:
  KeyError: 'prrsv12_qcpass'
Wildcards:
  samplename=prrsv12_qcpass
Traceback:
  File "/home/lisah/Pycharm/minor-HTHPC/snakemake/workflow/rules/typing.smk", line 12, in <lambda>
```

The error shows that the wildcard used is `prrsv12_qcpass`, but the wildcard is `prrsv12` + `prrsv12_qcpass` is the filename of an output of the `apply_qc` rule.

2. The second error is something I hope I already fixed, but it shows more info than the previous error:

```
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules apply_qc and typing are ambiguous for the file output/typing/prrsv12_qcpass.csv.
Consider starting rule output with a unique prefix, constrain your wildcards, or use the ruleorder directive.
Wildcards:
        apply_qc: samplename=prrsv12
        typing: samplename=prrsv12_qcpass
Expected input files:
        apply_qc: output/typing/prrsv12.csv output/consensus/prrsv12.fasta output/counts/prrsv12_summary.csv
        typing: data/prrsv/vaccines.fasta output/consensus/prrsv12_qcpass.fasta
Expected output files:
        apply_qc: output/typing/prrsv12_qcpass.csv output/consensus/prrsv12_qcpass.fasta
        typing: output/typing/prrsv12_qcpass.csv
```

As said before, the wildcard for `typing` is wrong, but the wildcard for `apply_qc` is correct (?????). Likewise, the expected input for `typing` is not `output/consensus/prrsv12_qcpass.fasta` but `output/consensus/prrsv12.fasta`.

I hoped I fixed the `AmbiguousRuleException` by using the `rules.<rule>.output` syntax and adding a ruleorder. As for the first error, I am completely lost and have no idea why this happens. It seems like an error with the wildcard, but I have no idea how the `_qcpass` part is added to the wildcard. It also seems like this error happens at random: Some runs work fine and others it crashes into this (Yes, run with the same data).

EDIT:

I tried running it with the `--debug-dag` and the only thing that popped out is the following:

```
selected job readcap
    wildcards: samplename=prrsv20_qcpass
file output/fastq/prrsv20_qcpass_readcap.fastq.gz:
    Producer found, hence exceptions are ignored.

candidate job select_centroid
    wildcards: samplename=prrsv20_qcpass
candidate job featurecounts
    wildcards: samplename=prrsv20_qcpass
candidate job map2ref
    wildcards: samplename=prrsv20_qcpass
candidate job apply_qc
    wildcards: samplename=prrsv20
selected job apply_qc
    wildcards: samplename=prrsv20
```

The `_qcpass` is added to the wildcard for the rest of the pipeline, but seems to work fine for `apply_qc`? `apply_qc` is one of the last rules in the pipeline...

Comment: Try running with `--debug-dag` to see which rules snakemake decides to run.  The gist is you have a cycle somewhere due to how your outputs are structured.  An easy fix is to put the output of each rule in a separate directory (e.g. a unique prefix).  You could also constrain your wildcard for samplename to not contain '_qcprefix', but constraints are usually specified as what the wildcard *can* be instead of a negative condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you misunderstood what ambiguous rules mean for `snakemake`, why you should avoid them and why `ruleorder` will not solve your problem.

First of all, here's a MWE - a minimal working example which reproduces your issue. Note that it is easier for everyone if you provide such an example and the call used to run `snakemake`.

In this case, the problem can be reproduced by calling `snakemake -call`:

```py
rule polish_consensus:
    output:
        "consensus/{samplename}.fasta",
    shell:
        """
        echo polish_consensus > {output[0]}
        """


rule typing:
    input:
        rules.polish_consensus.output,
    output:
        "typing/{samplename}.csv",
    shell:
        """
        cat {input[0]} > {output[0]}
        """


rule apply_qc:
    input:
        rules.typing.output,
        rules.polish_consensus.output,
    output:
        typing="typing/{samplename}_qcpass.csv",
        consensus="onsensus/{samplename}_qcpass.fasta",
    shell:
        """
        echo qcpass > {output[0]}
        echo qcpass > {output[1]}
        """


rule all:
    default_target: True
    input:
        expand(rules.apply_qc.output[0], samplename="prrsv12"),
        expand(rules.apply_qc.output[1], samplename="prrsv12"),
```

Your wildcard `{samplename}` will be matched by `snakemake` against all the output-files you request as well as files `snakemake` has to generate to run the workflow.

Now requesting `typing/prrsv12_qcpass.csv` matches the output of `rule apply_qc` with `samplename=prrsv12` as well as `rule typing` with `samplename=prrsv12_qcpass`. To prevent this you should constrain your wildcard rather than trying a `ruleorder` or using references to a `rules.<name>.output`.

By using a `wildcard_constraint` you tell `snakemake` which strings a wildcard can match. In your case, your `samplename` is presumably never going to contain an underscore, i.e. you can use:

```py
wildcard_constraints:
    samplename="[a-zA-Z0-9]+",
```

to tell `snakemake` to match against small/capital letters an numbers from 0-9, but not any whitespace or other symbols like underscore. This will make `snakemake` never consider `prrsv12_qcpass` as the wildcard value for `samplefile`, but only `prsv12` as the wildcard and `_qcpass` as an additional, fixed part of the filename.

More on `wildcard_constraints` can be found in the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/additional_features.html#constraining-wildcards)

Putting everything together into a single `Snakefile`:

```py
wildcard_constraints:
    samplename="[a-zA-Z0-9]+",

rule polish_consensus:
    output:
        "consensus/{samplename}.fasta",
    shell:
        """
        echo polish_consensus > {output[0]}
        """


rule typing:
    input:
        rules.polish_consensus.output,
    output:
        "typing/{samplename}.csv",
    shell:
        """
        cat {input[0]} > {output[0]}
        """


rule apply_qc:
    input:
        rules.typing.output,
        rules.polish_consensus.output,
    output:
        typing="typing/{samplename}_qcpass.csv",
        consensus="onsensus/{samplename}_qcpass.fasta",
    shell:
        """
        echo qcpass > {output[0]}
        echo qcpass > {output[1]}
        """


rule all:
    default_target: True
    input:
        expand(rules.apply_qc.output[0], samplename="prrsv12"),
        expand(rules.apply_qc.output[1], samplename="prrsv12"),
```

Comment: Since this is a project for an extern company, I cannot reveal the samplenames. I can tell that there are underscores in the original samplenames, so this would not work. Sorry for not concluding that in the post, I just don't want to get into trouble... But wouldn't this only delay the problem? Somehow Snakemake changes the wildcard which should not happen. Any ideas how this could be?

Comment: It's not delaying, but a design question. Snakemake somehow needs to distinguish the `samplename` from the remaining filename. You can either do that using the wildcard_constraints (maybe you can find a different regex which matches the `samplename`s without `_qcpass`. Or you can setup a directory structure where the samplename is clearly isolated, e.g. `typing/{samplename}/qcpass.csv` and `typing/{samplename}/original.csv`. Or you modify the filename to be e.g. `<samplename>~qcpass.csv` and exclude `~` via wildcard constraint, so that snakemake knows `qcpass` is not part of the wildcard.